# Excel 2007: Macro to save file on share drive

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I am writing a macro in Excel and I am trying to save a .txt file to a share drive. I have tried both sets of code below and I get 'Run-time error '76': Path Not Found".  Is this the correct syntax for file path?

```
FilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\\server.name\$foldername"
sOutPutFile = "filename.txt"

FilePath = "\\server.name\$foldername"
sOutPutFile = "filename.txt"
```

I get the error on the following line:

```
Open FilePath & sOutPutFile For Output As #nFileNum
```

Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need a "\" between FilePath and sOutPutFile:

```
Open FilePath & Application.PathSeparator & sOutPutFile For Output As #nFileNum
```

Comment: +1 I like your use of the generic `Application.PathSeparator` instead of the system-specific `\\` ! Very portable.

Comment: I ended up using: FilePath = "\\server.name\$foldername" &"\"
sOutPutFile = "filename.txt" and that worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think @Doug Glancy hit the nail on the head. You're missing a `\` between `FilePath` and `sOutPutFile`, and his solution works in your particular case. In general, however, it isn't always obvious whether the `FilePath` already has a `\` at the end of it or not, and this requires testing before concatenating the strings for a more general case.

Another approach is to use the FileSystemObject's [`BuildPath` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0z2z1zt%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), which does this testing automatically, i.e. inserts an additional path separator between the existing path and the filename only if necessary.

```
Dim FSO As Object
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Open FSO.BuildPath(FilePath, sOutPutFile) For Output As #nFileNum
```